# SPARK - How to use function in group by query

Tags: apache-spark, shark-sql

I am going to migrate  **SHARK**  query into  **SPARK**  .

Below is my sample  **SHARK**  query which use function in group by clause.

```
select month(dt_cr) as Month,
   day(dt_cr)   as date_of_created,
   count(distinct phone_number) as total_customers        
from customer
group by month(dt_cr),day(dt_cr);
```

This same query not working in  **SPARK**  sql, it gives the below error;

**Error :**  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Expression not in GROUP BY.

So as a part of solution i am using below SPARK query, That is working but required code change. It is big impact on my existing project. So anyone have a better solution with minimum impact.

```
SELECT Month,date_of_created,count(distinct phone_number) as total_customers        
FROM
(select month(dt_cr) as Month,
    day(dt_cr)   as date_of_created,
    email
from customers)A
group by Month,date_of_created
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue in Spark SQL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4296

However, I think it will be fixed in the next release. For now, you have to change your codes to bypass this issue.